# Put JSON data to freemarker list after ajax success responce

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, freemarker

I'm using freemarker to generate divs for news

```
<#if news?has_content>
<#list news as n>
    <div class="post-block">
            <h3>${n.getAuthor().name}
            <p>${n.getText()}</p>
    </div>
</#list>
</#if>
```

Also I have ajax request to get events or other news. Its structure is the same.

```
$.ajax({
        'url': '/get_news',
        'data': {
            'filter': some_value
        },
        'type': 'get',
        'success': function (json) {
            ???
        }
    })
};
```

How can I add the json data from ajax response to divs generated by freemarker? Is it possible to put the data directly to freemarker list and show the updated list?

Comment: need more details about data and expected results it needs to produce. You need to understand that freemarker runs on server long before page is sent to browser where the ajax is run so whatever you do in ajax success will need to be done on existing html already created by server

Comment: @charlietfl thank you. Seems like I need to use jQuery append() function